# choose the True statement?

Tags: complex-analysis

let f(z) be the meromorphic  function fiven by  function $f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-e^z).\sin z}.$  then  choose  the  True  statement

a) For every $ k$ $\in$ Z \ {0} ,$ z= k\pi$  is  a simple pole

b) $z= \pi + 2\pi i$  is  a pole

My attempts : I think  both  option a) and b)  are  True

because  for  option a) $e^z  = 1,$ $ e^z = e^{2n \pi i}$,  Now $sink\pi =0$

similarly   for  option b)  $sin( \pi + 2\pi i)= sin\pi = 0$

Is its  correct  or not ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The only zros of the sine function or the integer multiples of $\pi$. In particular, $\sin(\pi+2\pi i)\neq0$.

But, yes, statement a) is true.

Comment: how  $sin(\pi + 2\pi i) \neq  0$??  im not getting  can u  elaboarate  more

Comment: Why should it be $0$. Of course, $\sin(\pi+2\pi i)=-\sin(2\pi i)$. But$$-\sin(2\pi i)=-\frac{e^{-2\pi}-e^{2\pi}}{2i}\neq0.$$